# Splitting a string at a certain substring?

Tags: java, string, split

I am writing the beginning stages of some code which I will expand on in the next few months. The part I am working on now just takes a string. I have this down, but I want to split the string at a certain place:"(li)". So far I have:

```
String[] s = n.split("(li)")
```

But this is not compiling. The error says:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method split(java.lang.String)
location: variable s of type java.lang.String[]
```

Comment: Please show the bigger picture.

Comment: It works fine as long as n is of type String

Comment: Assuming you add a `;` to the end of the line.

Comment: Also note that the string as you have it will match any letter combination `li` as the `()` will be passed as a regular expression group

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String n = "mylitx";
        String[] s = n.split("(li)");
        for (String tag : s)
            System.out.println(tag);
    }
```

will produce the output as

```
my
tx
```

Comment: Consider the input `"the list of the little (li) groups"`. What will your output be now, OP is not very clear on which result they want however.

Comment: Then the results will be 

    "be the"
    "st of the" 
    "ttle ("
    ") groups" 

as expected. It will look at the patter l and i together and split